# Cassandra port usage - how are the ports used?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

When experimenting with Cassandra I've observed that Cassandra listens to the following ports:

- TCP *:8080
- TCP *:8888
- TCP *:57311
- TCP *:57312
- TCP 127.0.0.1:7000
- TCP 127.0.0.1:9160
- UDP 127.0.0.1:700

How does Cassandra use each of the ports listed?

Comment: adamse: Thanks for the tip! That's probably so, but for the sake of future Cassandra users on Stackoverflow (a growing population!) I thinks it good to have the answer stored here too :-)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

@Schildmeijer is largely right, however port 7001 is still used when using [TLS Encrypted Internode communication](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/InternodeEncryption)

So my complete list would be for current versions of Cassandra:

- 7199 - JMX (was 8080 pre Cassandra 0.8.xx)
- 7000 - Internode communication (not used if TLS enabled)
- 7001 - TLS Internode communication (used if TLS enabled)
- 9160 - Thrift client API
- 9042 - CQL native transport port

Comment: Here is the up-to-date link as of 2017 to the official documentation http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html#what-ports

Answer (score 54):

For Apache Cassandra 2.0 you need to take into account the following **TCP** ports:
(See [EC2 security group](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html) configuration and [Apache Cassandra FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#ports))

### Cassandra

- **7199** JMX monitoring port
- **1024 - 65355** Random port required by JMX. Starting with Java 7u4 a specific port can be specified using the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` property.
- **7000** Inter-node cluster
- **7001** SSL inter-node cluster
- **9042** CQL Native Transport Port
- **9160** Thrift

### DataStax OpsCenter

- **61620** opscenterd daemon
- **61621** Agent
- **8888** Website

### Architecture

A possible architecture with Cassandra + OpsCenter on EC2 could look like this:
[image: AWS EC2 with OpsCenter]

Answer (score 37):

8080 - JMX (remote)

8888 - Remote debugger (removed in 0.6.0)

7000 - Used internal by Cassandra
(7001 - Obsolete, removed in 0.6.0. Used for membership communication, aka gossip)

9160 - Thrift client API

Cassandra FAQ [What ports does Cassandra use?](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/faq/index.html#what-ports)

Answer (score 7):

JMX now uses port 7199 instead of port 8080 (as of Cassandra 0.8.xx).

This is configurable in your cassandra-env.sh file, but the default is 7199.

Answer (score 5):

Ports 57311 and 57312 are randomly assigned ports used for RMI communication. These ports change each time Cassandra starts up, but need to be open in the firewall, along with 8080/7199 (depending on version), to allow for remote JMX access. Something that doesn't appear to be particularly well documented, but has tripped me up in the past.

Comment: For posterity, this annoyance should be fixed, from Cassandra 2.0.8 onward [according to this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7087). The default `cassandra-env.sh` now sets the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` property to the same value as the main JMX port so that random ports are not used.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, as part of configuring your firewall, if you are using SSH then use port 22.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved issue using below steps :

1. Stop cassandara services

   ```
   sudo su -
   systemctl stop datastax-agent
   systemctl stop opscenterd
   systemctl stop app-dse
   ```
2. Take backup and Change port from 9042 to 9035

   ```
   cp /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/bkp_cassandra.yaml
   Vi /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
   native_transport_port: 9035
   ```
3. Start Cassandra services

   ```
   systemctl start datastax-agent
   systemctl start opscenterd
   systemctl start app-dse
   ```
4. create cqlshrc file.

   ```
   vi  /root/.cassandra/cqlshrc

   [connection]
   hostname = 198.168.1.100
   port = 9035
   ```

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: The question was not about changing what port Cassandra listens to for client connections.