# Expanding a Cassandra cluster with one additional node: what ports need to be open?

Tags: cassandra

Assume a Cassandra cluster with hosts `A` and `B`. This cluster shall now be extended with another host `C`. Assume that `C`is on a firewalled network were all packets are dropped by default.

Which ports and protocols must be opened up between `C <> A` and `C <> B` for the new node `C` to function properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7000 TCP (the internal communication port)
Btw, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used/2359212#2359212)