# how to change port number

Tags: networking, cassandra

I m new to cassandra.
Where is the port number 8080 is stored?
how can i change the port number?

Hello Schildmeijer,

i m not getting this : -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 (%JAVA_OPTS%)
can u please explore more

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used) question

8080 is used for remote JMX connection

*Windows*: **cassandra.bat**, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 (%JAVA_OPTS%)

*Linux*:   **cassandra.in.sh**, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 ($JVM_OPTS)

Comment: Hello Schildmeijer,Thanks.You have given me the perfect solution.thanks a lot.

Comment: You can just change the JMX port in cassandra-env.sh where it defines 'JMX_PORT="8080"'

Answer (score 1):

In OSX (and I guess also in Linux), this port is now located in `/conf/cassandra-env.sh`. You can change it by changing the `JMX_PORT` variable (line 165 in my case).

-frbl