# cassandra 1.2 nodetool getting 'Failed to connect' when trying to connect to remote node

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I am running a 6 node cluster of cassandra 1.2 on an Amazon Web Service VPC with Oracle's 64-bit JVM version 1.7.0_10.

When I'm logged on to one of the nodes (ex. 10.0.12.200) I can run `nodetool -h 10.0.12.200 status` just fine.

However, if I try to use another ip address in the cluster (10.0.32.153) from that same terminal I get `Failed to connect to '10.0.32.153:7199: Connection refused'`.

On the 10.0.32.153 node I am trying to connect to I've made the following checks.

- From 10.0.12.200 I can run `telnet 10.0.32.153 7199` and I get a connection, so it doesn't appear to be a security group/firewall issue to port 7199.
- On 10.0.32.153 if I run `netstat -ant|grep 7199` I see

  `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN`

  so cassandra does appear to be listening on the port
- The cassandra-env.sh file on 10.0.32.153 has all of the JVM_OPTS for jmx active

  `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

The only shot in the dark I've seen while trying to solve this problem while searching the interwebs is to set the following:

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.0.32.153"`

But when I do this I don't even get a response. It just hangs.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have reverse DNS configured?  JMX seems happiest when it is, so that IP resolves to hostname that resolves back to the same IP.

Comment: I don't believe reverse dns is available within the private subnets of a AWS VPC.

Answer (score 3):

The issue did end up being a firewall/security group issue. While it is true that the jmx port 7199 is used, apparently other ports are used randomly for rmi.  [Cassandra port usage - how are the ports used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used)

So the solution is to open up the firewalls then configure the cassandra-env.sh to include

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip>`