# Error - Apache Cassandra Datastax OpsCenter Community Edition Windows Noobie

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am experiencing errors with the Datastax Community Edition (datastax-community-64bit_1.2.6.msi) on two different machines both Windows 7 in both cases the OpsCentre is not working. This is immediately following install and I have not done anything other than follow the install-wizard. The following error pops up after OpsCenter finishes loading in the browser ("localhost:88888"):

> "Error loading events: ClusterServices instance has no attribute
>   'event_store'"

To give some context I am wanting to develop an ASP.NET MVC application using Cassandra back-end and am trying to get to grips with it using the [Chirper .NET app][1] as an example.

Many thanks,
H

---- The first few lines of the opscenterd.log

```
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Log opened.
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: twistd 10.2.0 (C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe 2.7.2) starting up.
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Logging level set to 'info'
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: OpsCenter version: 3.1.1
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Compatible agent version: 3.1.1
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Loading per-cluster config file C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\conf\clusters\local.conf
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: HTTP BASIC authentication disabled
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Starting webserver with ssl disabled.
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: SSL disabled
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer starting on 8888
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Starting factory <opscenterd.WebServer.OpsCenterdWebServer instance at 0x028E9C60>
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 []  INFO: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-07-31 15:51:39+0800 [] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\scripts\_twistw.py", line 47, in postApplication
        app.startApplication(self.application, not self.config['no_save'])
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\app.py", line 653, in startApplication
        service.IService(application).startService()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\service.py", line 277, in startService
        service.startService()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1141, in unwindGenerator
        return _inlineCallbacks(None, f(*args, **kwargs), Deferred())
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 54, in startService

      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\service.py", line 277, in startService
        service.startService()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\service.py", line 277, in startService
        service.startService()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\internet.py", line 110, in startService
        self._port = self._getPort()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\application\internet.py", line 131, in _getPort
        'listen%s' % (self.method,))(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 419, in listenTCP
        p.startListening()
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 857, in startListening
        raise CannotListenError, (self.interface, self.port, le)
    twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:61619: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling EventsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'event_store'
2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1198, in EventsController

2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling StorageCapacityController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 316, in StorageCapacityController

2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MissingAgentsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'agents'
2013-07-31 15:51:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1523, in MissingAgentsController

2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:49+0800 []  INFO: No handlers could be found for logger "orbited.proxy.ProxyIncomingProtocol"
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:51:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling EventsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'event_store'
2013-07-31 15:52:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1198, in EventsController

2013-07-31 15:52:48+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MissingAgentsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'agents'
2013-07-31 15:52:48+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1523, in MissingAgentsController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:52:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling EventsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'event_store'
2013-07-31 15:53:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1198, in EventsController

2013-07-31 15:53:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MissingAgentsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'agents'
2013-07-31 15:53:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1523, in MissingAgentsController

2013-07-31 15:53:50+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:50+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:51+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:51+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:52+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:52+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:53+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:53+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:54+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:54+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:53:55+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MetricsAggregateController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'cluster'
2013-07-31 15:53:55+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1445, in MetricsAggregateController

2013-07-31 15:54:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling MissingAgentsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'agents'
2013-07-31 15:54:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 133, in maybeDeferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1523, in MissingAgentsController

2013-07-31 15:54:49+0800 [] ERROR: Problem while calling EventsController: ClusterServices instance has no attribute 'event_store'
2013-07-31 15:54:49+0800 [] ERROR: 
      File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\lib\py-win32\2.7\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its permissions

I'm not super familiar with Windows so I'm not sure what would cause this.  Firewall?  Not running as Administrator?

Comment: I think that was it. I managed to fix by, stopping all the Datastax and Cassandra services and then restarting the TCP/IP stack. Run CMD as administrator, type “netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt” to reset TCP/IP. Now start the service again. I got this fix from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e0cc1b3e-2c63-451a-abc8-8e1e66a23287/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions)

Comment: Actually this is no longer working, I am getting the same error but this time the TCP/IP stack reset does not do much, and does not resolve the issue. Same error as before. Stuck, could do with some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's still error 10013, that usually means firewall/antivirus software prohibits access. Can you temporarily disable that? You may want to check the firewall/antivirus logs to see if you can allow access for OpsCenter (that's less risky than opening the machine up all the way). You may have to also open up ports for Cassandra (see here: [Cassandra port usage - how are the ports used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used)).

Thanks,
Sven