# datastax enterprise is crashing with exception while starting in cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am trying to setup DSE cluster. My seed node is working fine but when I try to run DSE service on cluster node it crashes with the exception

ERROR 09:46:47,271 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds!
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:947)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:716)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:554)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:451)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:347)
      at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:137)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:446)
      at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:334)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to contact any seeds!
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:947)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:716)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:554)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:451)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:347)
      at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:137)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:446)
      at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.main(DseDaemon.java:334)
Exception encountered during startup: Unable to contact any seeds!
ERROR 09:46:47,279 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:321)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.shutdownClientServers(StorageService.java:370)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.access$000(StorageService.java:88)
      at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:519)
      at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Can anybody please help me resolving this problem?

Jenish

Answer (score 1):

What version of DSE is this? Is this a single node machine? In general this would mean that the node is unable to contact any seed nodes in the ring. Are there any configured in your cassandra.yaml? Are those machines reachable, and are their firewalls allowing access?

Comment: I am using DSE 3.1. Yes I have done changes in Cassandra.yaml to add seed host IP address. I am able to ping seed host from this cluster node. Should I try to telnet to particular port of seed host?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used for the ports usually used by Cassandra. All those need to be reachable.

Comment: sdelmas - but then how do you bootstrap the first node of a new cluster, when no other nodes are yet reachable?

Comment: Are you starting the seed nodes first (is the node you are starting a seed node)?