# telnet refused on specific port on AWS instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I'm tryign to telnet from one linux env (10.205.116.141) to 10.205.117.246 on port 7199 but keep getting a connection refused. I did a `chkconfig iptables off` on both servers and even make sure iptables if stopped as well.

what else should I be looking at?

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# telnet 10.205.117.246 7199
Trying 10.205.117.246...
telnet: connect to address 10.205.117.246: Connection refused
```

trace route seems to be working as well...

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 bin]# traceroute 10.205.117.246 -p 7199
traceroute to 10.205.117.246 (10.205.117.246), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ip-10-205-117-246.xyz.cxcvs.com (10.205.117.246)  0.416 ms  0.440 ms  0.444 ms
```

also, I'm on a aws vpc so we don't get public IPs provisioned for use...

checked my security group and it looks like all ports are open as well

EDIT:

here is netstat as well, they look the same on both nodes:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-205-116-141 ~]$ netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46626             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36523               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2738                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.205.116.141:7000         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4445                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

shouldn't `127.0.0.1:7199` really be 10.205.116.141:7199?

sorry, can't post a sc of the security groups...

Comment: does "private cloud" mean "VPC" or "dedicated instance"? Please edit your question and show the result of `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` (and perhaps also include a screenshot of the security groups for 10.205.117.246, though this doesn't match up with SG behavior).

Comment: Your service running on port 7199 is binding to 127.0.0.1 which means its accessible within the local system itself only. I believe there's some bind configuration provided in your service which allows you to bind to 0.0.0.0:7199 .

Comment: I'm using cassandra on the 3 nodes but I don't see any service in the config file `cassandra.yaml` that uses port 7199. This quesion says its used by JMX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used...not sure what that is though...