# Retry connection to Cassandra node upon startup

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to use Docker to start my application and Cassandra database, and I would like to use Docker Compose for that. Unfortunately, Cassandra starts much slower than my application, and since my application eagerly initializes the `Cluster` object, I get the following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandra/172.18.0.2:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [cassandra/172.18.0.2:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1454)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
```

According to the stacktrace and a little debugging, it seems that Cassandra Java driver does not apply retry policies to the initial startup. This seems kinda weird to me. Is there a way for me to configure the driver so it will continue its attempts to connect to the server until it succeeds?

Comment: You only have one Cassandra node?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sure; I don't need more for local development and tests, at least for now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to write some try/catch logic on the NoHostAvailableException to retry the connection after a 5-10 second wait.  I would recommend only doing this a few times before throwing the exception after a certain time period where you know that it should have started by that point.

Example pseudocode

```java
Connection makeCassandraConnection(int retryCount) {
    Exception lastException = new IllegalStateException();
    while (retryCount > 0) {
        try {
            return doConnectionStuff();
        } catch (NoHostAvailableException e) {
            lastException = e;
            retryCount--;
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
        }
    }
    throw lastException;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it seems this is what I'll have to do. It is very strange that the driver does not do this automatically. I will probably create a ticket for this feature in their bug tracker.

Comment: What if multiple threads are trying to call this method? All the other threads have to wait and it's a performance hit right?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change your client code, and your client application's docker container stops because of the error you can use the following attribute for the client app in your docker-compose file.

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

That will restart your client application container as many times as it fails. Example docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.5
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: demo
  app:
    image: your-app
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, but it does not work if the application restart is not free (e.g. if it has some initialization to do). At the moment my program does not need to do any complex initialization, but it is highly likely that it will need something like it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The Datastax driver cannot be configured this way.

If this is only a problem with Docker and you do not wish to change your code, you could consider using something such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) which is a simple script which will wait for a TCP port to be listening before starting your application. [9042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359159/cassandra-port-usage-how-are-the-ports-used) is cassandra's native transport port.

Other options are [discussed here in the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), but I personally have only used wait-for-it but found it to be useful when working with cassandra within docker.

Comment: Actually, I'm currently using [`goss`](https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss) exactly for this purpose. Among everything else, it is able to check for the availability of a TCP port. But, naturally, I would want the driver to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612290/10428392

You could modify docker compose file like this with a health check.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  applicaion-service:
    image: your-applicaion-service:0.0.1
    depends_on:
      cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy


  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:4.0.1
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u cassandra", "-p cassandra" ,"-e describe keyspaces"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

Answer (score -1):

If you orchestrating many dockers, you should go for a docker compose with depends on tag

```
version: '2'
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.5
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: demo
  app:
    image: your-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
```

Comment: The depends on tag only waits for the container to be initiated, Cassandra itself will still take some extra time to startup.

Comment: Yep, `depends_on` does not actually work, this is the first thing I have tried.

Comment: even more, depends_on's condition have been removed in docker 3, so you can no longer wait until Cassandra is healthy

Answer (score -2):

Try increasing the connection timeout, it's the one thing sometimes happens on AWS and the like. I think you're looking at a late stage in the error log, at some point it should tell you it couldn't connect because of a timeout or unreachable network, and then it flags nodes as not available.

Using phantom, code is like below:

```
val Connector = ContactPoints(Seq(seedHost))
    .withClusterBuilder(_.withSocketOptions(
      new SocketOptions()
      .setReadTimeoutMillis(1500)
      .setConnectTimeoutMillis(20000)
    )).keySpace("bla")
```

### Resource Link:

[com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException #445](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/issues/445)

Comment: Cassandra hasn't started listening for clients in the OP's example. Connection attempts will be rejected as nothing is listening on the corresponding port. A timeout won't change that.