# How to start service when not healthy?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I've in `Dockerfile` service which depends on another service, but I'd like to negate the condition when **not** `service_healthy`. So opposite of the following:

```
service1:
    depends_on:
      service2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

So basically I'd like to start service1 when service2 is not healthy.

Secondly, based on the [documentation for `depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on), the `condition` option has been removed and it is no longer supported in version 3 of Compose file format.

So how the above logic can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround where `main` container waits for other hosts to exit, by pinging the other hosts and waiting when both are off-line:

```
version: '3'
services:
  main:
    image: bash
    depends_on:
     - test01
     - test02
    command: bash -c "sleep 2 && until ! ping -qc1 test01 && ! ping -qc1 test02; do sleep 1; done &>/dev/null"
    networks:
      intra:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.254
  test01:
    image: bash
    hostname: test01
    command: bash -c "ip route && sleep 10"
    networks:
      intra:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.11
  test02:
    image: bash
    hostname: test02
    command: bash -c "ip route && sleep 20"
    networks:
      intra:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.0.12
networks:
  intra:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.10.0.0/24
```

See also: [Docker compose - Start service only when other service had completed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48092592/55075)